# Replace all plus signs (+) with space in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not sure how to escape '+' in regex. Plus can come multiple times in `i` so we need to replace all `+` in the string. Here's what I have:

```
i.replace(new RegExp("+","g"),' ').replace(new RegExp("selectbasic=","g"),'').split('&');
```

But this gives me this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /+/: Nothing to repeat

Comment: `i.split('+').join(' ')` comes to mind, if you'd like to avoid regex.

Comment: @adeneo nice. more generalized replace all, would work on any substring in a string. should I be worried with the cost of splitting and joining?

Comment: I wouldn't think efficiency is an issue -> http://jsperf.com/split-vs-regexppp

Comment: Looks like you want to parse a URL. Then just use the [URL API](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/URL).

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The `+` character has special significance in regular expressions. It's a [quantifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Quantifiers) meaning one or more of the previous character, character class, or group.

You need to escape the `+`, like this:

```
i.replace(new RegExp("\\+","g"),' ')...
```

Or more simply, by using a precompiled expression:

```
i.replace(/\+/g,' ')...
```