# Replace arbitrary number of plus signs with spaces

Tags: html, regex, replace, notepad++

I have more than 2000 `<img>` tags and I want to replace alt text for each one of them. Alt text are like:

1. alt="pinblock"
2. alt="Rich+Austin+shop+4"
3. alt="hot+dry+sun+az"

I want a quick way to replace all '+' with space (' '), hence I'm using regex to fix this.
I've tried this so far:

**Find what:** `alt="(\D+)[+](\D+)[+*](\D*)[+*](\D*)[+*](\D*)[+*](\D*)[+*](\D*)[+*](\D*)"\s`

**Replace With:** `alt="\1 \2 \3 \4 \5 \6 \7 \8"`

I know I'm doing something wrong, please help.

Complete string would be:

`<img border="0" height="111" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-WL5_jMT96p4/U8ILVU9D-mI/AAAAAAAAGeI/rP_RJccbhj8/s1600/hot+dry+sun+az.jpg" alt="hot+dry+sun+az" width="200" />`

Comment: Can you please clarify about output?

Comment: What **language** are you trying to do this in? You can't parse HTML with a 
 regex. You can do *exactly* what you're trying to do in JavaScript [**rather easily**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22822463/2341603) though.

Comment: I mentioned platform in Topic, This is for notepad++, (find and replace)

Comment: What I'd do would be find `(alt=".*)\+(.*")` and replace with a space, then just repeat the operation until Notepad++ reports no matches. And you also want to do a [non-greedy search](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions) for the closing `"`.

Comment: Akash KC, It works fine when there are more than 4 or 5 (+) , and doesn't works on digits.

Comment: @KenY-N That won't work. First, you would have to also restore what you have captured and consumed in parenthesis.  Second, for a term like `term1+term2+term3`, if you replaced _and_ consumed the first two terms, then you'd miss the second plus (I think).

Comment: @Ken Y-N, and replace with? and I think it won't stop on alt attribute, what if there is "width" attribute after "alt" attribute as stated in example.

Comment: My opinion is that Notepad++ is not the best place to be doing this replacement.  It would be much easier using something like Java or C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to demonstrate, I have tested this out and repeated pressing of the `Replace All` button works. First, press the `Regular expression` radio button, then:

```
Find what:    (alt=\"[^+"]*?)\+([^\"]*?")
Replace with: \1 \2
```

This is of course not fool-proof, but it should work as long as you have no pathological data.

**NOTE**: My first version had a bug in that it would change `alt="hot+dry+sun+az" width="200+200"` to `alt="hot+dry+sun+az" width="200 200"`, which is a good example of why one should not use regex to process HTML. I think this task can probably be done in a few lines of JavaScript with zero danger of getting tripped up as I did above, but that's another question for another day!

**NOTE 2**: My second version also got [Zalgoed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8418417).

Comment: Great! Works fine. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Good - I've updated the regex as I found a problem that you could easily encounter. You should really do this with a proper HTML parser, though!